Jupiter Terminal input mint configuration
I'm integrating Jupiter terminal in my next.js project and I want to know how to fix my input mints to SOL and USDT only.
      const mod = await import('@jup-ag/terminal')
      const init = mod.init
      const SOL_MINT = 'xyzzy'
      const USDT_MINT = 'asana'
      init({
        displayMode: 'widget',
        endpoint: QUICKNODE_URL,
        formProps: {
          fixedInputMint: true,
          fixedOutputMint: true,
          initialInputMint: SOL_MINT,
          initialOutputMint: XYZ_PUBLIC_ADDRESS
        }
      })

      setInitialized(true)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to load Jupiter Terminal:', error)
    }
  }, [QUICKNODE_URL, XYZ_PUBLIC_ADDRESS])

